# Why .getOutput(0) is needed after GetCount_management?

Tags: arcpy

```
parcelCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("Parcels_lyr").getOutput(0))
print parcelCount
while parcelCount < 200:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Parcels_lyr","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",\
                                           "Parcels_lyr","150","ADD_TO_SELECTION")
    parcelCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("Parcels_lyr").getOutput(0))
    print parcelCount
```

The above was part of code. I don't understand the use and the need of getOutput(0). A reference said "because parcelCount is a python object and not a simple variable, you must add .getOutput(0) at the end of the object to reference the value's index number." I am totally confused. I look up online, including python doc, but seems not so much helpful info available.

I also searched this site. There is 1 post mentioning it, but not much.

Can anybody explain it?